# Handle feedback-Messages with a custom validation framework/object in apache wicket

Tags: apache, validation, error-handling, wicket

I am using my own validation, but the view of the form (e.g. if a component is invalid) should be highlighted or customized within wicket...

So e.g. 
I have my Wicket Form

```
<form wicket:id="inputForm">
         <p>
             <label for="Recipient">Recipient</label>
             <input wicket:id="Recipient" id="Recipient" type="text" size="40"/>
         </p>
         <p>
             <label for="Details">Details</label>
             <input wicket:id="Details" id="Details" type="text" size="40"/>
         </p>
</form>
```

Then I have my Form.java: Here I set the values of my Java Object "Invoice" and use **onValidateModelObjects** to override the wicket validation and use my own validation...
This method just calls a simple own created ValidatorObject that takes care of the validation...

```
public InvoiceForm() {
    ...

    Form<Invoice> form = new Form("inputForm", formModel) {
        /*
         * Validation takes place here
         */
        @Override
        public void onValidateModelObjects() {
            ValidationProcess vp = new ValidationProcess();
            vp.validate("Rules.js", r);
            msg = "";
            if (vp.getConstraintViolations().size() > 0) {

                for (String s : vp.getConstraintViolations()) {
                    msg = msg + s;
                }
            } else {
                msg = "no errors.";
            }
        }
    };

    //adding Textfields to the Form etc...

...
}
```

What I need: Above you can see that my errorMessages will be saved into the msg String! Now what I want is Wicket to take this String and apply it to the Wicket FeedBackMessage System or however...

1. I need to get the component that will be rendered at the moment...
2. I have to set the error Message of this component to my component...

how can I do that?

I guess I need to override some methods, but I dont know which ones and where...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following Code:

```
...
//Textfields or Form Components GO HERE...

        @Override
        public void onValidateModelObjects() {
            ValidationProcess vp = new ValidationProcess();
            vp.validate("Rules.js", r);
            msg = "";
            if (vp.getConstraintViolations().size() > 0) {

                for (String s : vp.getConstraintViolations()) {
                    if (s.contains(";")) {
                        String[] splitted = s.split(";");
                        String elementname = splitted[0];
                        String errorMessage = splitted[1];

                        if (elementname.equals("price")) {
                            //SET Error of Component 
                            price.error(elementname + " " + errorMessage + ". ");
                          } else if (elementname.equals("recipient")) {
                            recipient.error(elementname + " " + errorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//Rest of the Code
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special component, [FeedbackPanel](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/FeedbackPanel.html), which is showing validation and submission errors on the page. So add FeedbackPanel to the page with the form.

Then [Form.error()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.html#error%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) method registers an error feedback message for this component to be shown on FeedbackPanel. For example,

```
    @Override
    public void onValidateModelObjects() {
        ValidationProcess vp = new ValidationProcess();
        vp.validate("Rules.js", r);
        if (vp.getConstraintViolations().size() > 0) {
            msg = "";
            for (String s : vp.getConstraintViolations()) {
                msg = msg + s;
            }
        } else {
            msg = "no errors.";
        }
        error(msg, null);
    }
```

Also note, that you can define and attach an implementation of [IFormValidator](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/validation/IFormValidator.html) to a form with [Form.add()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.html#add%28org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.validation.IFormValidator%29) method to perform validation for you.

Comment: How does Form.error() exactly work? Assume I have 2 componentes = 2 Textfields.... 1.Textfield called price and 2. Textfield called recipient.... I add those to my form.... Now how can I get the textfield price and set the errorMessage of price to the message saved int the msg..... you wrote error(msg,null); But for which component will this be used?

Comment: I need something like this inside my ValidateModelObjects() method: if(component.name = price) then set error to msg. if(component.name = recipient) then set error to msg. and so on...

Comment: Form.error() registers a string about error to be shown in FeedbackPanel to the user. In Form.onSubmit() you can check Form.hasErrors() to check if any errors have been registered.

Comment: I almost have it... but how can I register the error at the component itself... because i have added a red border to the component, and it will be highlighted only when the component throws an error... so I need to register the error at the component too...

Comment: Thanks Dave! Worked for me as well!